# How to get query string parameters in java play framework?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, request.querystring

I'm very new to java play framework. I've set up all the normal routes like /something/:somthingValue and all the others. Now I want to create route the accepts query parameters like

/something?x=10&y=20&z=30

Here I want to get all the params after "?" as key==>value pair.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can wire in your query parameters into the routes file:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/JavaRouting in section "Parameters with default values"

Or you can ask for them in your Action:

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        final Set<Map.Entry<String,String[]>> entries = request().queryString().entrySet();
        for (Map.Entry<String,String[]> entry : entries) {
            final String key = entry.getKey();
            final String value = Arrays.toString(entry.getValue());
            Logger.debug(key + " " + value);
        }
        Logger.debug(request().getQueryString("a"));
        Logger.debug(request().getQueryString("b"));
        Logger.debug(request().getQueryString("c"));
        return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    }
}
```

For example the `http://localhost:9000/?a=1&b=2&c=3&c=4` prints on the console:

```
[debug] application - a [1]
[debug] application - b [2]
[debug] application - c [3, 4]
[debug] application - 1
[debug] application - 2
[debug] application - 3
```

Note that `c` is two times in the url.

Comment: I'm not able to see getQueryString() method of request(). is it because I'm using play 2.0 and you're using 2.0.4 ?

Comment: You are right, http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.0/java/play/mvc/Http.Request.html does not contain getQueryString() but request().queryString() can give you all you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. can you suggest me some good tutorials on it? Except it's documentation.

Comment: Great, then please mark my answer accepted. A list of Play tutorials can be found on https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/DMZB0J9JREE

Comment: One more issue, as play 2.0 has not getQueryString() method and Arrays.toString(entry.getValue()) returns value with [] what if I don't want those [] ? I just want value as we're getting with getQueryString() method. Do I've to switch to latest version of Play ?

Comment: I solved it, and it was silly mistake. I just did entry.getValue()[0]

Answer (score 22):

In Play 2.5.x, it is made directly in `conf/routes`, where one can put default values:

```
# Pagination links, like /clients?page=3
GET   /clients              controllers.Clients.list(page: Int ?= 1)
```

In your case (when using strings)

```
GET   /something            controllers.Somethings.show(x ?= "0", y ?= "0", z ?= "0")
```

When using strong typing:

```
GET   /something            controllers.Somethings.show(x: Int ?= 0, y: Int ?= 0, z: Int ?= 0)
```

See: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaRouting#Parameters-with-default-values for a longer explanation.

Answer (score 10):

You can get all query string parameters as a Map:

```
Controller.request().queryString()
```

This method return a `Map<String, String[]>` object.

Answer (score 0):

In `Java/Play 1.x` you get them with:

```
    Request request = Request.current();
    String arg1 = request.params.get("arg1");

    if (arg1 != null) {
        System.out.println("-----> arg1: " + arg1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FormFactory](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaForms#Handling-a-form-that-is-not-related-to-a-Model):

```
DynamicForm requestData = formFactory.form().bindFromRequest();
String firstname = requestData.get("firstname");
```