# Play framewrok querystring doesn't work for getJSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, playframework

I'm trying to use the jQuery's getJSON function with Play framework. And I'm passing a query string with it. But it looks like it does not getting the value, only the key

Here's my jQuery function:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        $.getJSON(
        '/getJsonResult',
        {'foo':'bar'},
        function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(i, result) {
            if(i != undefined) {

              var result_html = '<ul><li>';
              result_html    += result + '<\/li><\/ul>';

              $('#result_container').append(result_html);
            }
          });
        }
        );  
      });
  });
</script>
```

Here's the action method:-

```
public static Result getJsonResult() {
    Map queryParameters = request().queryString();

    List data = Arrays.asList("result", "This is just a test");

    if (queryParameters != null) {
    System.out.println("QS Key ---> " + queryParameters.containsKey("foo"));
    System.out.println("QS Value ---> " + queryParameters.containsValue("bar"));
    }

    return ok(Json.toJson(data));
}
```

The output:-

```
[info] play - Application started (Dev)
QS Key ---> true
QS Value ---> false
```

Comment: This may help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907996/how-to-get-query-string-parameters-in-java-play-framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in [How to get query string parameters in java play framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907996/how-to-get-query-string-parameters-in-java-play-framework)

I had to use a Map type to get the relevant key, value pair.

Answer (score 1):

It's because queryString method has Map type. Anyway, you can access value of "foo" key by calling queryParameters.get("foo").